# Does installing .NET Framework 4.7 eliminate the need to install 4.6.x?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

Our environments currently have

```
.NET Framework 2.0        50727
.NET Framework 3.0        30729
.NET Framework 3.5        30729
.NET Framework 4.5.2     379893
```

Rolling out 4.7 this week. Will an application targeting 4.6.x use 4.7, or do I need to install 4.6 also?

Comment: Yes, 4.7 *overwrites* any previously installed 4.x version.  Make sure you don't also install 4.6, that will destroy the 4.7 install.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [Installing the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx):

> All of the .NET Framework versions listed in the following table are in-place updates to the .NET Framework 4. In other words, if you install a later version, such as the .NET Framework 4.6, you do not first have to install the previous versions, such as the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2

.NET 4.7 is the topmost entry in the table that follows. Which means that once it's installed, you cannot/do not need to install 4.6 (any variant)

Comment: Just to double confirm: I have a service built targeting 4.6, now I have it it deployed on a machine that has 4.7.2 installed, that means my service (without any change) *automatically* benefits from what's included in 4.7.2 (most notably CLR JIT/GC upgrades), right?

Comment: @WeipengL - that's correct. Any performance or *security* concerns addressed in later versions of the framework will benefit you (as will any bug fixes). If there are breaking changes in behaviour caused by later framework versions (and your testing reveals an issue) there are usually ways to ask for the older behaviour via configuration, but by default you're opted into the latest everything.

Comment: I'm not able to build solution written in 4.6.1 after installing 4.7.2. What is suggested solution?

Comment: @PramodJangam You need to install the developer pack of the 4.6.1, then you'll be able to build projects in that version.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what are the ways to ask for the older behaviours?

Comment: @LeonardoChaia That's really a new question, but you'll need to know what specifically is broken. For brevity: If you're rebuilding, update your app to work with the new behaviour, don't ask for old behaviour.